# Delphi soap response save to xml?

Tags: delphi, soap-client

How can I save soap response to xml? I tried with tstringlist, filestream, created the xml file but, but I got

> could not convert varinat of type (null) into (type (olestr)

I tried this simple code.The response is not empty.The file size 40MB. Delphi XE3.

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1AfterExecute(const MethodName: string;
SOAPResponse: TStream);
var xml : TStringlist;
begin
 xml := TStringlist.create;
  try
    soapresponse.Position:=0;
    xml.LoadFromStream(SOAPResponse);
    xml.SaveToFile('...file.xml');
 finally
  xml.Free;
 end;
end;
```

this is the problem(empty lines)? or not ?

```
...

- <leiras>
- <![CDATA[ 
*  Socket AM2 for AMD Athlon™ 64FX / 64X2 / 64 and Sempron processors
* ULi M1697

1. Supports FSB 1000MHz (2.0GT/s), Hyper-Transport Technology and AMD Cool 'n' Quiet   Technology
2. Untied Overclocking : During Overclocking, FSB enjoys better margin due to fixed PCIE/ PCI Buses
3. Supports Dual Channel DDRII800/667/533, 4 x DIMM slots, with maximum capacity up to 8GB
4. Hybrid Booster - ASRock Safe Overclocking Technology
5. Supports Dual Graphics XLI
6. 1 x PCI Express x16 slot
7. 1 x PCI Express x 8 slot, to adopt 2nd PCI Express x 16 VGA card and other PCI Express x4, x2, x1 interface cards
8. 2 x PCI Express x1 slots
9. 4 x Serial ATA II 3.0Gb/s, support RAID (RAID 0, 1, 0+1, JBOD and RAID 5), NCQ, AHCI and "Hot Plug" functions
10. 2 x eSATAII 3.0Gb/s, support NCQ, AHCI and "Hot Plug" functions
11. HDMI_SPDIF header, providing SPDIF audio output to HDMI VGA card, allows the system to connect HDMI Digital TV/projector/LCD devices.
12. 7.1 Channel with High Definition Audio
13. Windows Vista™ Premium Logo Hardware Ready
14. ASRock 8CH_eSATAII I/O: 2 eSATAII ports, HD 7.1 channel audio jacks


]]> 
</leiras>
<kepek /> 

...
```

i tried NullStrictConvert := False; no convert error,but the exe using 1GB RAM,until i close it.

```
...
var xml : TStringlist;
begin
xml := TStringlist.create;
NullStrictConvert := False;
 try
  soapresponse.Position:=0;

...
```

Comment: @Lacika your delphi version is important, breakpoints are your best friends.

Comment: This looks correct to me, we do something very similar to log our responses.  Time to put in some debug statements, maybe a ShowMessage on the first 255 chars or something like that.

Comment: i added breakpoint. xml.savetofile Ok->created a file,open soap.rio unit,break (error) at this line : FConverter.ProcessResponse(RespXML, IntfMD, MethMD,Context, FHeadersInbound)

Comment: The code shown here does not involve any variants. Your problem lies elsewhere. Use the debugger.

Comment: raised exception class EVariantTypeCastError with message 'could not...'

Comment: By using a TStringList you may apply undesired ANSI-Unicode conversions in your saved soap response. If you want to preserve it the way it was received, don't use a TStream but directly save the stream to the disk, for example, using a TFileStream.

Comment: Try to use xml as `TFileStream` and use `xml.CopyFrom(SOAPResponse, SOAPResponse.Size)`

Comment: @Lacika: On what line exactly does the exception occur?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try dumping your stream directly to a file, to see what’s in there?

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1AfterExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPResponse: TStream);
var 
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create('C:\Downloaded.xml', fmCreate);
  try
    FS.CopyFrom(SoapResponse, 0);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm for what @kobik suggests, `TFileStream` is even more readable for this intention. [+1]

Comment: @Lacika: Does this code trigger a `could not convert variant of type (null) into (type (olestr)`?!?  On which line does the exception occur?

Comment: i'm amatuer,and my english is not very good :) [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVGFaGS1l_o)

Comment: @Lacika: Thank you! But Instead of clicking [Continue], you should click [Break], and tell us on which line you are then. **That** is where the error really occurs.  In the meantime, I suggest you **delete** this question, and create a new one with THAT code.

Comment: Also, open the file `C:\Downloaded.xml`, and look inside. Perhaps you'll be able to see what the problem is...

Comment: after the break button ...[link](http://youtu.be/99VNybE5uf4).in the xml file a lot of data,end lot of "empty line".

Comment: @Lacika: Empty lines shouldn't be a problem; that’s perfectly valid in XML. But I repeat my suggestion: delete this question, and create a new question with the line(s) of code you end up on after the break. Also, take a course on **debugging**, or find tutorials about it. It’s going to make your life so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the stream's Read method to a temporary string variable:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1AfterExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPResponse: TStream);
var
  s: string[200];
  ds: string;
  n: Longint;
  xml: TStringList;
begin
  SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
  xml := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ds := EmptyStr;
    while SOAPResponse.Position < SOAPResponse.Size do begin
      n := SOAPResponse.Read(s[1], 200);
      SetLength(s, n);
      xml.Text := xml.Text + ds;
    end;

    xml.SaveToFile('...file.xml');
  finally
    xml.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird.
 
Maybe this example helps.
I'm doing almost the same thing, logging the response and request to a TMemo.
Also, my 'Before' routine fills the actual SOAPRequest from an external FSoapData TStringStream:

```
procedure TFrmTestEWS.HTTPRIOBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
var
   TS: TStringStream;
   S : String;
begin
   // 1. Fill request
   SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
   FSoapData.Position := 0;
   SOAPRequest.CopyFrom(FSoapData,FSoapData.Size);
   SOAPRequest.Size := FSoapData.Size;
   // 2. Logging
   S := 'Request:' + #13#10#13#10;
   TS := TStringStream.Create(S);
   try
      TS.Position := Length(S);
      FSoapData.Position := 0;
      TS.CopyFrom(FSoapData,FSoapData.Size);
      TS.Position := 0;
      MmoLog.Lines.LoadFromStream(TS);
   finally
      TS.Free;
   end;
end;

procedure TFrmTestEWS.HTTPRIOAfterExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPResponse: TStream);
var
   TS: TStringStream;
   S : String;
begin
   S := MmoLog.Text + #13#10#13#10 + 'Response:' + #13#10#13#10;
   TS := TStringStream.Create(S);
   try
      TS.Position := Length(S);
      SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
      TS.CopyFrom(SOAPResponse,SOAPResponse.Size);
      TS.Position := 0;
      MmoLog.Lines.LoadFromStream(TS);
   finally
      SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
      TS.Free;
   end;
end;
```